# package-lock.json changes not affecting builds as expected

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

We have an Nx powered repo hooked up to Nx cloud and are benefitting from the cache time savings.

One thing we have just come across is that we have an open pull request where some dependencies have had some patch bumps and as a result only our package-lock.json file has changed.

We issue the following commands in our Jenkins pipeline:

```
steps {
    echo "GATE 2 - Build"
    sh "npx nx affected --base=origin/integration --target=build --parallel --max-parallel=3"
    sh "npx nx affected --base=origin/integration --target=test --parallel --max-parallel=3"
}
```

When Nx runs these, it does not detect any changes for the build targets and retrieves results from our cache. But for the tests it does re-run these all again.

We would expect both build and tests to be re-run due to there being dependency bumps.

Is this expected behaviour, are we misunderstanding how the hashing works?

I did try adding `package-lock.json` as an implicit dependency `"package-lock.json": "*"` to our `nx.json` in case I needed to force it be used somehow. But it looks like this should already be being considered as per this [line of code](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/workspace/src/core/hasher/hasher.ts#L223)

So can anyone shed any light on what could be happening here, are we doing something incorrect, or misconfigured something somewhere perhaps?

Comment: can you add your angular.json file so we can see it?

Comment: what about the angular.json file are you most interested in?

Comment: the rules you wrote to how things get done on test, serve and build.

Comment: I thing both `angular.json` and `package.json` file will be usefull

Comment: But did you run a pipeline at some point with this or was it the first one? If it was already done at some point (like on a previous commit or something similar), then you must have rebuilt the cache therefore re-running the pipeline should give you instant build?